# Using Functions of `a` on `newtype a`

Tags: haskell, newtype

Let's say I have the following `newtype`:

`newtype Foo = Foo Integer deriving (Eq, Show)`

Is there a concise way to add two `Foo`'s:

`(Foo 10) + (Foo 5) == Foo 15`

or get the max:

`max (Foo 10) (Foo 5) == Foo 5`?

I'm curious if it's possible to easily use functions of `a` for a `newtype a` rather than do:

```
addFoo :: Foo -> Foo -> Foo
addFoo (Foo x) (Foo y) = Foo $ x + y
```

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51915219/is-there-a-shorthand-for-operations-like-fromnewtype-f-tonewtype

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Just as haskell98 knows how to derive those `Eq` and `Show` instances for you, you can turn on the `GeneralizedNewtypeDeriving` extension to ghc to get the `Num` and `Ord` instances you need:

```
Prelude> :set -XGeneralizedNewtypeDeriving 
Prelude> newtype Foo = Foo Integer deriving (Eq, Show, Num, Ord)
Prelude> (Foo 10) + (Foo 5) == Foo 15
True
Prelude> max (Foo 10) (Foo 5) == Foo 5
False
```

Comment: Is using this technique considered idiomatic?

Comment: @KevinMeredith Yes, it is idiomatic.  But just for your own enlightenment you should try writing the `Ord` and `Num` instances yourself.

Answer (score 11):

You want to lift functions of the type `Integer -> Integer -> Integer` to `Foo -> Foo -> Foo`. To do so you could define utility functions:

```
liftFoo :: (Integer -> Integer) -> Foo -> Foo
liftFoo f (Foo a) = Foo $ f a

liftFoo2 :: (Integer -> Integer -> Integer) -> Foo -> Foo -> Foo
liftFoo2 f (Foo a) (Foo b) = Foo $ f a b

-- and so on
```

Then you could use it as follows:

```
liftFoo2 (+) (Foo 10) (Foo 5)

liftFoo2 max (Foo 10) (Foo 5)
```

This has the advantage of not requiring an extension.

---

Another option is to make the definition of the `Foo` newtype more permissible so that you could make it an instance of `Functor` and `Applicative`:

```
import Control.Applicative

newtype Foo a = Foo a deriving (Eq, Show)

foo :: Integer -> Foo Integer
foo = Foo

instance Functor Foo where
    fmap f (Foo a) = Foo $ f a

instance Applicative Foo where
    pure = Foo
    (Foo f) <*> (Foo a) = Foo $ f a
```

Now you could do the following:

```
(+) <$> foo 10 <*> foo 5

max <$> foo 10 <*> foo 5
```

Because `foo` is specialized to the `Integer` type you don't lose any benefits of type checking.

Comment: Note that there are several libraries offering general versions of `liftFoo` and `liftFoo2`: For example `newtype-generics`, the original `newtype`, or more recently `coercible-utils`.

Answer (score 4):

You can also use *safe coercions* for this. Roughly you use `Data.Coerce.coerce` to automatically wrap/unwrap the newtype.

```
> import Data.Coerce
> newtype Foo = Foo Integer deriving (Eq, Show, Ord)
> coerce (Foo 1) :: Integer
1
> let f :: Integer -> Integer ; f x = x + 1
> coerce f (Foo 10)
Foo 11
>  coerce (succ :: Integer -> Integer) (Foo 10) :: Foo
Foo 11
> coerce (max :: Integer -> Integer -> Integer) (Foo 10) (Foo 5) :: Foo
Foo 10
```

Note that it works great with monomorphic functions as `f`, but less so with polymorphic functions such as `succ`, since in the latter case a type annotation is required.

Answer (score 3):

To get mathematical operations, you will need to make `Foo` an instance of the `Num` typeclass. This means that you will have to define `(+)`, `(*)`, `abs`, `signum`, `fromInteger`, and either `negate` or `(-)` for `Foo`. Once you have defined these functions, you will get the rest of the functions that work on `Num` for free.

To get `max` and similar functions to work, you will need to make `Foo` an instance of `Ord`. This requires definitions of either `compare` or `(<=)`.

In general, you can use `:t` in ghci to find the type of a function, which includes the typeclasses which it works with. Then you just have to determine what minimal set of functions you have to define for that typeclass.

Answer (score 1):

There are several libraries that offer combinators for lifting functions on the underlying type to the newtype.

For the examples you give, you could use the `over2` combinator that is available from [`newtype-generics`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/newtype-generics) with type

```
over2 :: (Newtype n, Newtype n', o' ~ O n', o ~ O n) => (o -> n) -> (o -> o -> o') -> n -> n -> n'
```

or from [`coercible-utils`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/coercible-utils) with type

```
over2 :: (Coercible a b, Coercible a' b') => (a -> b) -> (a -> a -> a') -> b -> b -> b'
```

Usage (for the version from `coercible-utils`) is like this:

```
λ over2 Foo (+) (Foo 10) (Foo 5) :: Foo
Foo 15
```