# Is there a shorthand for operations like `fromNewtype . f . toNewtype`?

Tags: haskell, newtype, coerce

A pattern that presents itself the more often the more type safety is being introduced via `newtype` is to project a value *(or several values)* to a `newtype` wrapper, do some operations, and then retract the projection. An ubiquitous example is that of `Sum` and `Product` monoids:

```
λ x + y = getSum $ Sum x `mappend` Sum y
λ 1 + 2
3
```

I imagine a collection of functions like `withSum`, `withSum2`, and so on, may be automagically rolled out for each `newtype`. Or maybe a parametrized `Identity` may be created, for use with `ApplicativeDo`. Or maybe there are some other approaches that I could not think of.

I wonder if there is some prior art or theory around this.

**P.S.**   I am unhappy with `coerce`, for two reasons:

- **safety**   I thought it is not very safe. After being pointed that it is actually safe, I
  tried a few things and I could not do anything harmful, because it requires a type annotation
  when there is a possibility of ambiguity. For example:

  ```
  λ newtype F = F Int deriving Show
  λ newtype G = G Int deriving Show
  λ coerce . (mappend (1 :: Sum Int)) . coerce $ F 1 :: G
  G 2
  λ coerce . (mappend (1 :: Product Int)) . coerce $ F 1 :: G
  G 1
  λ coerce . (mappend 1) . coerce $ F 1 :: G
  ...
      • Couldn't match representation of type ‘a0’ with that of ‘Int’
          arising from a use of ‘coerce’
  ...
  ```

  But I would still not welcome `coerce`, because it is far too easy to strip a safety label and
  shoot someone, once the reaching for it becomes habitual. Imagine that, in a cryptographic
  application, there are two values: `x :: Prime Int` and `x' :: Sum Int`. I would much rather
  type `getPrime` and `getSum` every time I use them, than `coerce` everything and have one day
  made a catastrophic mistake.
- **usefulness**   `coerce` does not bring much to the table regarding a *shorthand* for
  certain operations. The leading example of my post, that I repeat here:

  ```
  λ getSum $ Sum 1 `mappend` Sum 2
  3
  ```

  — Turns into something along the lines of this spiked monster:

  ```
  λ coerce $ mappend @(Sum Integer) (coerce 1) (coerce 2) :: Integer
  3
  ```

  — Which is hardly of any benfit.

Comment: See my answer regarding your criticism of `coerce` as shorthand. You don't coerce the inputs and outputs (that is indeed little if any better than applying newtype constructors/getters); instead `coerce` the *function* you want to call so it has a different type. As for safety; it's no more or less safe than manually unwrapping. If you want to make that impossible, don't export the newtype constructors, and `coerce` won't work either. If you can mess up with coerce, you can also mess up with manual newtype unwrapping.

Comment: I agree with your uneasiness about coerce -- though coerce won't do anything that you couldn't otherwise do safely.  In particular, newtypes are not coercible *unless their constructors are in scope*.  So if you are properly using [smart constructors](https://wiki.haskell.org/Smart_constructors), for example, coerce can't hurt you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your "spiked monster" example is better handled by putting the summands into a list and using the `ala` function available [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/coercible-utils-0.0.0/docs/CoercibleUtils.html#v:ala), which has type:

```
ala :: (Coercible a b, Coercible a' b') 
    => (a -> b) 
    -> ((a -> b) -> c -> b')   
    -> c 
    -> a'
```

where

- `a` is the *unwrapped* base type.
- `b` is the newtype that wraps `a`.
- `a -> b` is the newtype constructor.
- `((a -> b) -> c -> b')` is a function that, knowing how to wrap values of the base type `a`, knows how to process a value of type `c` (almost always a container of `a`s) and return a wrapped result `b'`. In practice this function is almost always [`foldMap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Foldable.html#v:foldMap).
- `a'` the *unwrapped* final result. The unwrapping is handled by `ala` itself.

in your case, it would be something like:

```
ala Sum foldMap [1,2::Integer]
```

"ala" functions can be implemented through means other than `coerce`, for example [using generics](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/newtype-generics-0.5.3/docs/Control-Newtype-Generics.html#v:ala) to handle the unwrapping, or even [lenses](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.17/docs/Control-Lens-Wrapped.html#v:ala).

Comment: I'm happy to see `coercible-utils` mentioned here! :) Would you mind changing the link to `ala` to http://hackage.haskell.org/package/coercible-utils-0.0.0/docs/CoercibleUtils.html#v:ala though? This way it's more clear that `coercible-utils` is available from Hackage.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, there's! It's a [`coerce`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Coerce.html#v:coerce) function from `base` package. It allows to convert from `newtype` and to `newtype` automatically. GHC actually has a big chunk of theory behind coercions.

In [`relude`](https://github.com/kowainik/relude) I called this function `under`.

```
ghci> newtype Foo = Foo Bool deriving Show
ghci> under not (Foo True)
Foo False
ghci> newtype Bar = Bar String deriving Show
ghci> under (filter (== 'a')) (Bar "abacaba")
Bar "aaaa"
```

You can see the whole module here:

- http://hackage.haskell.org/package/relude-0.2.0/docs/Relude-Extra-Newtype.html

It's also possible to implement custom functions for binary operators as well:

```
ghci> import Data.Coerce 
ghci> :set -XScopedTypeVariables 
ghci> :set -XTypeApplications 
ghci> :{
ghci| via :: forall n a . Coercible a n => (n -> n -> n) -> (a -> a -> a)
ghci| via = coerce
ghci| :}
ghci> :{
ghci| viaF :: forall n a . Coercible a (n a) => (n a -> n a -> n a) -> (a -> a -> a)
ghci| viaF = coerce
ghci| :}
ghci> via @(Sum Int) @Int (<>) 3 4
7
ghci> viaF @Sum @Int (<>) 3 5
8
```

Comment: I should have mentioned that `coerce` is unsuitable for this purpose, since it defies type safety.

Comment: @IgnatInsarov Why does `coerce` defy type safety? Are you sure you're not thinking of `unsafeCoerce`?

Comment: @IgnatInsarov This is a common misconception. `coerce` is completely safe. You can't `coerce` integer to string for example. It's possible with `unsafeCoerce` only.

Comment: @DavidYoung Not like totally defies. It is just that I do not trust myself with it. See the postscriptum I added to my question.

Comment: @IgnatInsarov It's possible to implement function like `via @Sum @Int (<>) 3 4` which results into `3 + 4` using `coerce`.

Comment: @Shersh Yes, it sounds like a perfect fit. I think it would be great if you expand your answer with the definition and use of this function. It is a great use case for `TypeApplications`, too. I wonder if we could draft a `viaN` function that lifts a function of any number of arguments this way.

Comment: @IgnatInsarov I've added `via` function. It's an open question how to support it for arbitrary number of variables. Though, I guess, well-known trick with polyvariadic functions could work.

Answer (score 6):

`coerce` from [Data.Coerce](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.1.0/docs/Data-Coerce.html) can be pretty great for this sort of thing. You can use it to convert between different types with the same representation (like between a type and a newtype wrapper, or vice versa). For example:

```
λ coerce (3 :: Int) :: Sum Int
Sum {getSum = 3}
it :: Sum Int

λ coerce (3 :: Sum Int) :: Int
3
it :: Int
```

It was developed to solve the problem that it is cost-free to e.g. convert an `Int` into a `Sum Int` by applying `Sum`, but it isn't necessarily cost-free to e.g convert a `[Int]` to a `[Sum Int]` by applying `map Sum`. The compiler might be able to optimise away the traversal of the list spine from `map` or it might not, but we know that the same structure in memory can serve as either a `[Int]` or a `[Sum Int]`, because the list structure doesn't depend on any properties of the elements and the element types have identical representation between those two cases. `coerce` (plus the [role system](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#roles)) allows us to make use of this fact to convert between the two in a way that is guaranteed not to do any runtime work, but still have the compiler check that it's safe to do so:

```
λ coerce [1, 2, 3 :: Int] :: [Sum Int]
[Sum {getSum = 1},Sum {getSum = 2},Sum {getSum = 3}]
it :: [Sum Int]
```

Something that wasn't at all obvious to me at first is that `coerce` is not limited to coercing "structures"! Because all it's doing is allowing us to substitute types (including parts of compound types) when the representations are identical, it works just as well to coerce *code*:

```
λ addInt = (+) @ Int
addInt :: Int -> Int -> Int

λ let addSum :: Sum Int -> Sum Int -> Sum Int
|     addSum = coerce addInt
| 
addSum :: Sum Int -> Sum Int -> Sum Int

λ addSum (Sum 3) (Sum 19)
Sum {getSum = 22}
it :: Sum Int
```

(In the above example I had to define a monotype version of `+` because `coerce` is so generic the type system otherwise doesn't know which version of `+` I'm asking to coerce to `Sum Int -> Sum Int -> Sum Int`; I could instead have given an inline type signature on the argument to `coerce`, but that looks less tidy. Often in real usage the context is sufficient to determine the "source" and "target" types of the `coerce`)

I once wrote a library that provided a few different ways of paramterising types via newtypes, and provided similar APIs with each scheme. The modules implementing the APIs were full of type signatures and `foo' = coerce foo` style definitions; it felt really nice that I was barely doing any work other than stating the types that I wanted.

Your example (using `mappend` on `Sum` to implement addition, without having to explicitly convert back and forth) could look like:

```
λ let (+) :: Int -> Int -> Int
|     (+) = coerce (mappend @ (Sum Int))
| 
(+) :: Int -> Int -> Int

λ 3 + 8
11
it :: Int
```